# Jhipster + Angular 4 ( Blank page )

Tags: spring, angular, jhipster

I'm trying to generate an app with jhipster and angular 4. It works well with angular js, but with angular 4, i can run the app but i have a blank page, with no errors

How could i fix this ?

EDIT :

I run the app with intelliJ and got this :

[Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOUZF.png)

i tried yarn start and got this :

[Yarn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgCDC.png)

But this time it worked

I dont realy get the difference between the maven run of intellij, spring boot, yarn start or mvwn

Thanks

Comment: It's very difficult for the community to help you without more details.  Could you please edit your question to include what steps you have taken to diagnose the problem and what the exact error message is?

Answer (score 4):

Hit the F12 key and you will likely find the error in your browser ( the console tab). This will give you the problem ( may be an error when calling the backend). This is more a comment than an answer.

Just in case, make sure :

- You launched ./mvnw
- You launched yarn start
- In your browser : http://localhost:9000/yourApp